# Python hypothesis: Ensure that input lists have same length

Tags: python, testing, python-hypothesis

I'm using hypothesis to test a function that takes two lists of equal length as input.

```
import hypothesis.strategies as st
from hypothesis import assume, given


@given(
    st.lists(ints, min_size=1),
    st.lists(ints, min_size=1),
)
def test_my_func(x, y):
    assume(len(x) == len(y))

    # Assertions
```

This gives me the error message:

> FailedHealthCheck: It looks like your strategy is filtering out a lot
> of data. Health check found 50 filtered examples but only 4 good ones.

The assumption that `len(x) == len(y)` is filtering out too many inputs. So I would like to generate a random positive number and use that as the length of both `x` and `y`. Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: So when you pick this random positive number, what do you want to do to the lists to make them conform

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`flatmap`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/master/data.html?highlight=flatmap#chaining-strategies-together) to generate data that depends on other generated data.

```
import hypothesis.strategies as st
from hypothesis import assume, given
from hypothesis.strategies import integers as ints

same_len_lists = ints(min_value=1, max_value=100).flatmap(lambda n: st.lists(st.lists(ints(), min_size=n, max_size=n), min_size=2, max_size=2))

@given(same_len_lists)
def test_my_func(lists):
    x, y = lists
    assume(len(x) == len(y))
```

It's a little clumsy, and I'm not very happy about having to unpack the lists inside the test body.

Answer (score 16):

I found an answer using the `@composite` decorator.

```
import hypothesis.strategies as st
from hypothesis import given

@st.composite
def same_len_lists(draw):

    n = draw(st.integers(min_value=1, max_value=50))
    fixed_length_list = st.lists(st.integers(), min_size=n, max_size=n)

    return (draw(fixed_length_list), draw(fixed_length_list))


@given(same_len_lists())
def test_my_func(lists):

    x, y = lists

    # Assertions
```

Comment: This will return a tuple with a single list in both positions - you probably want to remove the draw() call so that `fixed_length_list` is a strategy, then `return (draw(ffl), draw(ffl))`.

Comment: @ZacHatfield-Dodds will that cause a change in the test cases? I don't fully understand how draw() works.

Comment: What is draw in this example code?

Comment: @myke It's provided by the `composite` decorator. See the hypothesis docs:
https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#composite-strategies

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions give nice reusable strategies. Here's a short low-tech solution, perhaps better suited to one-off use since you need to do one line of processing in the test function. We use zip to tranpose a list of pairs (2-element tuples); conceptually we're turning a `n x 2` matrix into a `2 x n` matrix.

```
import hypothesis.strategies as st
from hypothesis import given

pair_lists = st.lists(st.tuples(st.integers(), st.integers()), min_size=1)

@given(pair_lists)
def test_my_func(L):
    x, y = map(list, zip(*L))
```

Warning: It is crucial to have `min_size=1` because `zip` will give nothing if the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

What's about using dictionaries for this purpose?

You can specify generated data

For example if need only positive integers, use `min_value=1`. If don't need empty list - `min_size=1` for dictionary, etc.

```py
from hypothesis import given
from hypothesis.strategies import integers, dictionaries


@given(
    dicts=dictionaries(integers(min_value=1), integers(min_value=1), min_size=1)
)
def test_your_test(dicts):
    x = list(dicts.values()) # or just dicts.values()
    y = list(dicts.keys()) # or just dicts.keys()

    assert len(x) == len(y)
```

Same way you can generate any lists with same length (list of strings or whatever)